# why does `as.numeric` of a character with decimals add additional numbers

Tags: r

```
options(digits = 18)
x <- 0.127272727272727287
str(x)
# num 0.127
x
#[1] 0.127272727272727287
as.character(x)
#[1] "0.127272727272727"
as.numeric(as.character(x))
[1] 0.12727272727272701
```

Where does the `01` come from? What's going on here?

Comment: Because the closes floating point number that can represent `0.127272727272727` is `0.1272727272727270098062746228606556542217731475830078125`

Comment: And `as.character` represents real and complex numbers to 15 significant digits (from `?as.character`)

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/903061)

Comment: If you really want to get into the weeds, read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: happy to delete if the consensus is dupe. +1 responses

Comment: @user1320502 it's not really necessary to delete a duplicate.

Comment: Definitely don't delete - much better to leave this as a pointer to the other one. The answer is pretty much the same, but the question to get there is different. I'm not sure if it should be marked as a dupe (I didn't dupe-hammer close it). Let's see what answers come along and close it if nothing is substantially different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hinted at in the help page `?options` when you look at the section on digits. You can set the number of digits to any number up to 22, but that does not mean that R will accurately represent that many digits. R uses 
[IEEE double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  Wikipedia tells us that this representation has

> Sign bit: 1 bit
>   Exponent: 11 bits
>   Significand precision: 53 bits (52 explicitly stored)

So R is storing numbers to `log(2^53, 10) = 15.95459` decimal digits accuracy. Anything you get beyond that is luck.